# Traffic is not routed to Elastic Load Balancer even after Route 53 record is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a load balancer at [this URL](http://awseb-awseb-6gp7iyga1hvr-1677779325.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/), which points to a Beanstalk application running at [this URL](http://hostingdemo-env.eba-bcrxbyif.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/). Currently, it just returns the current time.

I'm trying to make the application available at [squadify.me](https://squadify.me), a domain name I own, via the load balancer.

After following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html) to create the necessary Route 53 record, I was expecting to be able to access the application (via the load balancer) at [squadify.me](https://squadfy.me). Am I missing something? The Route 53 records I currently have in place are shown below.

[image: Route 53 records for squadify.me]

Comment: When I try to resolve `squadify.me`, my computer tells me that it cannot resolve the domain name. When I try `nslookup squadify.me`, it says "no servers could be reached". Where did you purchase this domain name (eg GoDaddy or on Amazon Route 53)? If it is on Route 53, does it appear under 'Registered Domains' in the Route 53 console?

Comment: The EB url that works is different then in your R53. Why do you use `dualstack` there?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I purchased the domain using GoDaddy, then transferred it to Route 53 (where it now appears as a hosted zone and a registered domain) - if this has been done correctly, should I expect to see something come up from that nslookup command? It also returns a "can't find" error from my machine.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct Nameserver (NS) entries? To check you can click on **Registered Domains**, select your domain, choose "Add/edit name servers". If the name servers displayed are different to the ones in your screenshot above, then change them to match your screenshot. More info: [amazon web services - Deleted then recreated Route 53 hosted zones, now website not working - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/838330/deleted-then-recreated-route-53-hosted-zones-now-website-not-working)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - wow, that's done it, thank you very much! The previous namespaces I had for my registered domains were ns17.domaincontrol.com and ns18.domaincontrol.com - I guess I needed to change these after I transferred from GoDaddy?

Comment: If you want to leave that comment as an answer to this post, I'll mark it as the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Registered Domain** in Amazon Route 53 will be assigned a set of four **Nameservers**. The Nameservers reside in different top-level domains, such as `.co.uk`, `.net`, `.org` and `.com`.

The server numbers are randomly (but very specifically) chosen for each domain. It is important that the name servers associated with your domain are the same as the domain names listed in the `NS` record for the domain.

To see the correct servers to use, go to **Registered Domains**, select your domain and choose "Add/edit name servers". If they are different to the `NS` record, then edit the `NS` record to match the nameservers displayed.